# How to make WordPress create a query based on a slug?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-routing, slug

How to make WordPress create a query based on a slug ? For example I have my wordpress site url as http://example.com/.

I want to generate a page based on the slug provided on the url. This is a realty wordpress directory site. So I will just append the city/state name on the slug. Instead of creating a lot of pages how would I implement this way

```
http://example.com/texas
```

It will show all real estate agent members in texas. Then I could write my meta desc and other seo related metas to texas dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can base this on tags. Of course if your template supports tags taxonomy. For every single entry you need to add tag (Texas, Kentucky etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Simple use something like that

```html
   <?php  $the_query = new WP_Query('pagename=here_your_page_slug'); ?>
```